# Solving Thevinin question

Tags: circuit-design

[image]

these rectangles are the resistors 
my question is 
what is the method of solving this question in steps please?
no worries about the naming or the numbers anyone can assign any number. I just want the method to start for ex how would I solve the Rth which one will be canceled and which will be added and so on.

thanks

Comment: You could start by naming them, and showing your attempt at solving it on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the load across and A and B and then:

1) Find thevenin equivalent resistance, Rth across A and B by shorting voltage sources and opening current sources.

2) Find open circuit voltage, Vth across A and B. You can easily use superposition theorem since multiple sources are there.

3) Draw Thevenin. eq. circuit using Vth, Rth and load.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but after making short circuit for voltage and open for current, the two resistors next to the voltages sources are parallel to each other ? and what about the resistor the one alone at the right will it be included?

Comment: ONLY that resistor will be included. The two parallel ones are not included in Rth because their other ends are not connected. They are open. No current will flow through them if a voltage source is applied across AB. They can be neglected.

Comment: alright so Rth equals the number of the resistor infront of the terminals a and b, what about the Vth how to calculate it

Comment: Superposition theorem and KVL